VBA: Create Percent Change Array from Arrays
I have 24 named ranges that go down Column A to Row 24. For each, I want to calculate the percent change from the start to end for each cell in the array. Then return the resulting array of percentages as a new named range array.
So far I have:
Sub Pct_Chg()
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, rng As 
Range
For i = 1 To 24
   Set C2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IS").Range("A" & 
    i).Value
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IS").Range("Actual_" & i)
    For Each c In rng
    c.Value = ((c.Value - C2) / C2) * 100
    Next

    End Sub

I am a bit lost of whats next- any ideaS?

If you want the results to be a new named range then you need to place those % values into cells and name that range which has the calculated values

You have Set here where it's not required:  Set C2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IS").Range("A" &      i).Value

Firstly, do you understand what an array (in VBA) is? When you say "array" are you referring to a Range? Even so, if you have in mind to return a named range you have to know/tell us where to return such a Range. Fortunately, you can really return in an array, if you understand what I mean, but if you want returning a named range you need to drop the content of these specific arrays (for each iterated named range) in another range, then name it (so, a name is also needed for each).
